# Why does the unnamed register only contain the last deleted text when appending deleted text to a register?

Tags: register

The Vim documentation says the following under “quote_quote” about the unnamed register (`"`):

> Vim fills this register with text deleted with the “d”, “c”, “s”, “x” commands or copied with the yank “y” command, regardless of whether or not a specific register was used (e.g.  `"xdd`). This is like the unnamed register is pointing to the last used register. Thus when appending using an uppercase register name, the unnamed register contains the same text as the named register.

However, the part with uppercase register names does not work for me when deleting. I only get the last deleted text into the unnamed register. For example, when I enter `"add` and then `"Add`, register `a` contains both deleted lines, but the unnamed register only contains the last one, although it should contain the same text as register `a`. However, things work as expected with the yank (`y`) command. Why is this?

Comment: I never noticed. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: At least, this phenomenon exists with versions 7.3 and 7.4. Which version are you using?

Comment: I can reproduce it with 7.3

Comment: I can reproduce it with 8.0. Seems like a bug to me too.

Comment: What am I supposed to do if this question cannot be reasonably answered because it is actually a bug showing up? Should I just leave it open? Or “answer” it myself? Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is actually caused by a bug. This bug has been reported and discussed in the thread [*Unnamed register only contains the last deleted text when appending deleted text to a register*](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/p-iHvlpVkCM) on the `vim-dev` mailing list.

Comment: The link points to the current vi.SE Q/A, not to vim-dev thread on gmane/[googlegroups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/p-iHvlpVkCM)/[narkive](http://vim-dev.vim.narkive.com/68L2FJuK/unnamed-register-only-contains-the-last-deleted-text-when-appending-deleted-text-to-a-register)/...

Comment: Fixed. (The link now points to the respective Google Groups web page.)

Comment: posted a [patch](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/p-iHvlpVkCM/7Ey8zo1DBgAJ)

Comment: and already [included](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.0.0681)